# How to set a field equal to postId [METEOR]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the a posts model that I would like to allow users to "apply" to. Therefore, I have created an applications model using *aldeed collections 2* as follows:

```
applications = new Mongo.Collection('applications');

applications.attachSchema(
    new SimpleSchema({
    post: {
      type: String,
      autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
          return post._id;
        } else if (this.isUpsert) {
          return {$setOnInsert: post._id};
        } else {
          this.unset();
        }
      }
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
          return Meteor.userId();
        } else if (this.isUpsert) {
          return {$setOnInsert: Meteor.userId()};
        } else {
          this.unset();
        }
      }
    },

    bio: {
      type:String
    }
  })
);
```

Essentially, I need each application to "belong to" the post that it is being applied to, and the user who has created the application. I figured that the easiest way to do this in Meteor is to set the `post` value equal to postId. But how do I do this in Meteor? Is there a better way? I am coming from a Rails background.

P.S. I also use IronRouter.

Answer (score 1):

The code provided seems to be over-complicated, I would prefer to use following Schema:

```
 applications.attachSchema(
    new SimpleSchema({
    post: {
      type: String,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    bio: {
      type: String
    }
  })
);
```

And then add new items to the collection with:

```
var postID = posts.insert({}); // some code that inserts posts

applications.insert({post: postId, name: Meteor.userId(), bio: ''})
```

Also, as you use a document-oriented database `Mongo` you may want to combine all the related documents into one document instead of storing IDs of separate collections in `application` like you would do with a relation-oriented database.